# Is there a way to make a game that uses Python/pygame that will work through a web browser?

Tags: python, pygame, browser-based-games

Is there any framework or method that will allow to use browser to run a 2D game made in python with pygame graphical library?

Comment: The existence of sites like [Python Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/), [myCompiler](https://www.mycompiler.io/online-python-compiler), etc. seem to answer the question "is it possible to run Python code *through* a browser". Note that the browser isn't actually running Python code natively in these examples. The Python code is either running on a server with the output streamed to the browser to display, or it's being emulated in JavaScript through some type of transpiling. That's enough to show technical feasibility, but it doesn't mean it's a good idea for games. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DMGregory well, I just want to make a simple game that will not require to install anything on the gamers PC. I thought that was pretty obvious tbh, am I missing something here?

Comment: JavaScript would be a more typical language choice for that use case, since browsers run it natively. Anything you do in a browser these days will be going through JavaScript at some level, so having another language under that is an extra complication you'd likely want to avoid unless you have a hard requirement of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Since mid-2022, pygame has partial support for WebAssembly as upcoming python3.11 and allows for running the same pygame code on desktops and mobile/web.

You can publish your game on itch.io  or github pages as some people have already done.

use pygbag from https://pypi.org/project/pygbag , some documentation is available from pygame-web.github.io

read documentation to adjust your main loop for async, and then use  `python3 -m pygbag game_folder_with_all_extra_modules_and_assets/main.py`

Answer (score -1):

use replit [https://replit.com/~](https://replit.com/%7E). if you want to make your own website with your game iframe a replit in html

Comment: This concept is not super intuitive, could you show an example on how you'd do this?